# How to format font style and color in echo

Tags: php, fonts, format, echo

I have a small snippet of code that I want to style from echo.

```
foreach($months as $key => $month){
  if(strpos($filename,$month)!==false){
        echo '<style = "font-color: #ff0000"> Movie List for {$key} 2013 </style>';
    }
}
```

This is not working, and I've been looking over some resources to try to implement this. Basically I want font-family: Arial and font-size: 11px; and the font-color: #ff0000;

*Any* php assistance would be helpful.

Comment: You need to enclose the string in double quotes, not single quotes for variable interpolation

Comment: You need a ';' after style params.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach($months as $key => $month){
  if(strpos($filename,$month)!==false){
        echo "<div style ='font:11px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#ff0000'> Movie List for $key 2013</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It works with this code and your other code, too. I'm gonna start using <div>. Not a fan of <span>

Comment: Whatever problem you were having with <span> should affect <div>, too. Either they both get echoed or they both get interpreted.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "<span style = 'font-color: #ff0000'> Movie List for {$key} 2013 </span>";
```

Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes. Since the above uses double quotes for the PHP string, I switched to single quotes for the embedded HTML, to avoid having to escape the quotes.

The other problem with your code is that `<style>` tags are for entering CSS blocks, not for styling individual elements. To style an element, you need an element tag with a `style` attribute; `<span>` is the simplest element -- it doesn't have any formatting of its own, it just serves as a place to attach attributes.

Another popular way to write it is with string concatenation:

```
echo '<span style = "font-color: #ff0000"> Movie List for ' . $key . ' 2013 </span>';
```

Comment: I appreciate the information, but it still echo's everything from <span> ... </span>

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. The browser shold interpret it as HTML. If not, it seems like you have a server configuration problem, preventing it from sending the correct `Content-type: text/html` header.

Comment: Its not working... my code :: <?php echo  "<span style = 'font-color: #ff0000'>  $_product->getData('ayyappa_coupon_code_offer'); </span>"  ?>

Comment: @Rathinam You need curly braces if you're not substituting a simple variable. `{$_product->getData('ayyappa_coupon_code_offer')}`

Comment: @Barmar This my code still not applied font color : <?php echo "<span style = 'font-color: #ff0000'> {$_product->getData('ayyappa_coupon_code_offer')} </span>";?>

Comment: @Rathinam You should post a new question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
 echo "<a href='#' style = \"font-color: #ff0000;\"> Movie List for {$key} 2013 </a>";
```

Comment: Still not working. It echo's the entire code for that line. :/

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to echo out a style or an inline style?
An inline style would be like

```
echo "<p style=\"font-color: #ff0000;\">text here</p>";
```

Comment: this is what i'm trying to do, however, it still echo's the code, <p style="font-color: #ff0000;">text here</p> Maybe I'm doing something incorrectly?

Comment: When you say it's still echoing out the code, is it echoing out the code for all php on the page or just this segment?

Comment: I figured it out. Your code was correct as well. I had a small mistake but worked my way through it. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '< span style = "font-color: #ff0000"> Movie List for {$key} 2013 </span>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also use the style 'color' and not 'font-color'

```
<?php

foreach($months as $key => $month){
  if(strpos($filename,$month)!==false){
        echo "<style = 'color: #ff0000;'> Movie List for {$key} 2013 </style>";
    }
}

?>
```

In general, the comments on double and single quotes are correct in other suggestions.  $Variables only execute in double quotes.